# Entry Processes 20/ 20

Tags: mysql, linux, webserver, httpserver

On the Cpanel of my Linux server I see that the Entry Processes is 20/20 . When I connect to the website

> `Resource Limit Is Reached
>
> The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it
>   exceeded resource limit. Please try again later.`

1 I wanted to know how and what causes this increase in resource

2 What can I do to utilised it efficiently without getting it transferred to a new host.

Ny server is basically a Photo Viewing application . On a day I get about 400 visitors usually.

Comment: Something is starting a lot of processes or processes that run for a long time. I don't think anyone can tell you more than that unless you tell us what's on your server and what you're doing with it.

Comment: @octern Ny server is basically a Photo Viewing application . On a day I get about 400 visitors usually.

Comment: Do you have shell access? You could try using `ps` and `top` to see if any processes you own are hanging around inappropriately. Also, are you hitting 20 processes when the application is doing a bunch of things, or even when it's supposed to be idle?

Comment: @octern - I have the shell Access , but I cant access it right now.

Usually its Idle , but on peak time it reaches 20/20  (Evening time).
Does the number of connection to the website increases this Count ? How is it ?

Comment: I think it's the number of processes. More users will cause higher load, but it's not a 1:1 relationship. I don't really know how to help you; you might have better luck asking on serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and on my case, It was a programing problem. Everytime you request a query to the MySQL server thru PHP programing, you need to close the conection, otherwise it remains open for a long period of time.

If you close it inmediately with **mysql_close($con);** then it releases the so called "Entry Process" of the PHP program. I did my closings right after the query was succesfully performed.

So my advice is to close inmediately the DB connection after you do the query. And to make sure, at the end of the PHP program (last line of code), close it again, just in case, you miss to close one of them. Closing connections dont hurt your programing, just makes sure that you didnt left any open connections open, so other users can access them thus, your entries are closed too.

Good luck.